# Authentication status lost on page refresh

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a Blazor WebAssembly application that uses an OIDC authentication with a Keycloak identity server. The issue comes when after login, I manually refresh the page and then the authentication state gets completely lost, so it is needed to login again. I need to know if there is any way to persist in the authentication state so don't banish on refresh.